# Por que o ob_get_clean limpa a memória sem iniciar o buffer com ob_start()?

Tags: php, memória

Eu estava um dia fazendo uns testes, analizando como as funções influenciam no uso da memória, e, por um acaso, chamei a função `ob_get_clean()`.
Reparei que a chamada da função "diminuiu" o tamanho da memória usada pelo php.

Com `ob_start()` observei anteriormente que se aumentava o uso da memória, como era de se esperar, pois o mesmo guarda a saída num buffer.

Agora não entendo por que `ob_get_clean()` "limpou" algum valor do buffer, diminuindo a memória, sendo que `ob_start()` não foi chamado em lugar algum do código.

Abaixo segue os resultados que obtive:

```
<?php
echo memory_get_usage(); //122224
?>

<?php
ob_get_clean();
echo memory_get_usage(); //113992
?>
```

Alguém sabe por que ao chamar `ob_get_clean()` a memória diminuiu?

Existe alguma configuração no php.ini que inicia o buffer automaticamente ou coisa do tipo?

Comment: A diretiva `ob_implicit_flush` está desabilitada? Se sim, pode ser que o PHP esteja guardando o output na memória para, só no final, fazer com que o buffer seja liberado da memória.

Comment: Não seria `implicit_flush`? 
Eu encontrei essa linha no meu php.ini `implicit_flush = Off`. Está desabilitado.

Comment: Eu acabei de fazer o teste mudando essa diretiva para "On". Obtive resultados diferentes, porém quando uso `ob_end_clean` continua "diminuindo" o uso da memória. sem `ob_end_clean = 121808` e
com `ob_end_clean = 113576`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, existe.

No seu `php.ini` como está configurada a opção `output_buffering` ?

```
output_buffering=On
```

Ativa o buffer de saída automático.

Você pode desabilitá-lo:

```
output_buffering=Off
```

ou ainda especificar o tamanho do buffer:

```
output_buffering=4096
```

Veja mais: [Output Buffering no manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/outcontrol.configuration.php)

Comment: é exatamente isso!
Realizei os mesmo testes aqui!
No meu php.ini, essa opção estava marcada como **4096**.
Ao tentar chamar o ob_end_clean() recebi um erro:
`Notice: ob_end_clean(): failed to delete buffer. No buffer to delete in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste\index.php on line 2`